# Storing embeds in function for later discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is it possible? I have a seperate file `_embeds.py` with discord.py imported. I have the embed setup in the function with a `return embed` at the end, but when calling, it sends `<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x00000219A7514CA0>` instead of the embed. Is it possible to do this successfully?

**_embeds.py:**

```py
def setting_update_success(setting, value):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Success!",
                      description=f"Setting `{setting}` was updated to `{value}`.",
                      colour=0x19e63b,
                      timestamp=datetime.now())
    embed.set_author(name="Chix",
                    icon_url="attachment://chix_full.png")
    embed.set_footer(text="Sent")
    return embed
```

**main.py:**

```py
await channel.send(messages.setting_update_success())
```

[Output](https://imgur.com/a/X2B5yDi) (imgur)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending an embed you need to specify that it's an embed when sending like this:

```
await channel.send(embed=messages.setting_update_success())
```